# Scala fold with a function and initial value

Tags: scala

How do you implement a fold function given a generic function?

```
def dofold[A, B](list: List[A], func: (B, A) => B, initial: B): B
```

Comment: Do you want a left fold or a right fold? (Or would you accept either one?)

Comment: What have you tried? Show us code that didn't work.

Comment: The problem I have is that fold normally takes a func: (A, A) instead of (B, A).   
def fold[A1 >: A](z: A1)(op: (A1, A1) ⇒ A1): A1                                                       
I was able to do this without use fold but using a for loop. Was wondering if there was a way to use fold.                     
       var ret = initial
       for ( i <- 0 until list.length) {
         ret = func(ret, list(i))
       }
       ret

Answer (score 1):

You can look how it is implemented in Scala standard library or Haskell

https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L407
https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/collection/LinearSeqOptimized.scala#L122
https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/collection/LinearSeqOptimized.scala#L133

**https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl%27 (maybe this link is the best)**

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/Data.Foldable.html#foldr
http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/Data.Foldable.html#foldl